# Origin (and Derivative) of the Name Marlene?

Tags: person-names

I have read that "Marlene" Dietrich was originally named Maria Magdelena Dietrich. If this is true, would Marlene then be a contraction of of Maria Magdelena? Or did the name exist before Ms. Dietrich in other contexts for other people?

Born about the same time as Marlene Dietrich was a female film producer who went by the name "Leni." Apparently it was a contraction of the name Helene. Is Leni ONLY a reference to Helene, or can it be used to refer to women named Marlene, Arlene, Darlene, and similar names?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your finding is entirely correct. **[Marlene](http://vornamen.woxikon.de/vorname/marlene)** is a contraction fo [Maria](http://vornamen.woxikon.de/vorname/maria) and [Lena](http://vornamen.woxikon.de/vorname/lena) (short for Magdalena or Helena). This female name became popular by Marlene Dietrich, but was known before as we can see from this [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Marlene&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3).

Etymologic roots of **[Maria](http://www.vorname.com/index.php)** (*lat.* for Hebrew *"Mirjam"*) come from the Egyptian *mry* (*loved one*) and became one of the most popular names in Christian cultures. **[Magdalena](http://www.vorname.com/index.php)** is of Hebrew orgin too and became another popular name from the role she played as one of the few mentioned female followers of Jesus Christ. **[Helena](http://www.vorname.com/index.php)** on the other hand has Greek roots as [Helen of Troy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helen_of_Troy).

Comment: I would only add that the Biblical Magdalena wasn't the ONLY female follower but just the most famous. ;-) Otherwise great research!

Comment: Meinte nicht pingelig zu sein. :-p